# Android 7.0: install .apk

Tags: android, installation

**My Code:**

```
 public static void installApk(Context context, File apkFile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, 
        context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", apkFile);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

**apkFile path:**

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.me.myapp-1.0.1.apk

**Get Uri :**

```
content://com.me.myapp.provider/publicDir/Download/com.me.myapp-1.0.1.apk
```

The error I not get message.

Answer (score 1):

The error create by my little ignore.

1 manifest 中添加代码

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

2 res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path
            name="publicDir" path="/"/>
    </paths>
```

3 install

```
public static void installApk(Context context, File apkFile) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", apkFile);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
    }
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

you need this url

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

the code solution my problem. hope help you